# yacc - How to do a if condition

Tags: if-statement, grammar, yacc

I am trying to do a simple if condition from an input file.

i will have something like

```
if(color = black)
```

No matter what i do i keep getting 1 shift / reduce
I am very new to lex and yacc 
Do YACC grammars often have shift-reduce conflicts? and should i not worry about them?

My lex file will return every character in the file correctly so i wont show you the lex file

However, here is my yacc file:

```
%{

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

%}
 |IF LPAREN COLOR EQ BLACK RPAREN  {$$ = $1;  printf("WONT COMPILE\n");} 
     ;
```

in the yacc file i tried this but that is where i am getting the shift/ reduce

```
IF LPAREN COLOR EQ BLACK RPAREN {$$ = $1;  printf("If statement\n");}
```

SOLVED

Comment: YACC grammars often have shift-reduce conflicts, but it selects shift (which is usually the right behavior).  Don't worry about them too much.

Comment: When i did yacc -d programName.y   that's when  got the conflict: shift/reduce and then i naturally thought it wouldn't compile. It still complains but works. Thank you

Comment: @icelated, please don't put "[SOLVED]" in the title: either accept an answer, or if there's no correct answer, you could answer (and accept) your own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I originally wrote a long answer about the “dangling else” ambiguity, but then I took a closer look at your grammar.  Let’s cut it down to size a bit and demonstrate where the problems are:

```
%token IF COLOR BLACK
%%
statement
    : statement command
    | /*nothing*/
    ;

command
    : IF              {$$ = $1; printf ("IF\n");}
    | ELSE            {$$ = $1; printf("ELSE\n");}
    | EQ              {$$ = $1; printf("EQ\n");}
    | THEN            {$$ = $1; printf("THEN\n");}
    | LPAREN          {$$ = $1; printf("LPAREN\n");}
    | RPAREN          {$$ = $1; printf("RPAREN\n");}
    | COLOR EQ BLACK  {$$ = $3; printf("color is black\n");}
    | IF LPAREN COLOR EQ BLACK RPAREN  {$$ = $1;  printf("WONT COMPILE\n");} 
    ;
```

Just how do you expect the statement `if(color = black)` to be parsed?  Notice that the “`color = black`” can reduce to a `command` via `COLOR EQ BLACK` or can be “shifted” onto the stack to become part of the longer parse `IF LPAREN COLOR EQ BLACK RPAREN`.

That explains the specific warning you’re getting.  Now, on to the rest of your grammar:

You don’t want to be writing your grammar so incomplete statements are meaningful.  Notice that the single symbol “`=`” is a complete valid `command` and therefore a complete valid `statement`—is that really what you want?

You’re going to want to rewrite this from scratch.  Start simple:

```
%token NUMBER COMMAND IF THEN ELSE COLOR BLACK
%%
statement
    : COMMAND NUMBER
    | IF cond THEN statement
    | /* nothing */
    ;
cond
    : '(' COLOR '=' BLACK ')'
    ;
```

Not tested; but this should be enough to get you started.  If you need to do something when you encounter a token, you can (for example) replace `IF cond THEN COMMAND` with `if cond then command` and add rules like

```
if  : IF   { printf("%s\n", "IF"); }
    ;
then: THEN { printf("%s\n", "THEN"); }
    ;
```

Start simple, add slowly, and refactor when rules get too hairy or repetitive.  And work through a tutorial before you jump into a large project.  The [GNU Bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/) has a good tutorial, as does Kernighan & Pike’s [*The Unix Programming Environment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_Programming_Environment).

Comment: I will look over what you have later. For what i see it looks good.