# YACC: A token with another token one or more times (repetition)

Tags: yacc, lex, option-type, repeat

Require some assistance as my google fu seems to be weak in this task.

Got started with Lex/Yacc and so far so good however I have a strange requirement for this proof of concept I am conducting. I require repetition and optional tokens.

I have a text file that has the following content:

```
instance 0 {
    application 0 {
        id 0 {
            server 10.143.23.240
            server backup 10.132.34.240
        }
        id 24 {
            server 10.143.23.240
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the Lex is fine:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

%}

%%

\{                                                              return OBRACE;
\}                                                              return CBRACE;

instance                                                        return INSTANCE;
id[0-9]+                                                        return ID;
        application                                             return APPLICATION;
                id                                              return ID;
                        server                                  return SERVER;
                        backup                                  return backup;
                        [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+          { yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
                                                                        return SERVER_IPADDRESS; }
[0-9]+                                                          { yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
                                                                        return NUMBER; }
[ \t\n]+                                                        /* ignore whitespace */;
.                                                               printf("%s\n", "Incorrect syntax");
%%
```

The grammar/Yacc is as follows and has been simplified to provide context and does not show the repetition as I have no idea on how to tackle it:

```
commands: /* empty */
        | commands command
        ;

command:
        server
        ;

server:
        SERVER SERVER_IPADDRESS
        {
                char server_ip_from_yyval[257] = { '\0' };

                if(NULL == $2){
                        printf("%s\n", "SERVER_IPADDRESS is NULL");
                }
                else{
                        strncpy(server_ip_from_yyval, $2, 256);
                        set_server_ip(server_ip_from_yyval);
                }
        }
        ;
%%
$ 
$
```

So my challenges are:

1.) How to allow "id" in the text file or ID in the Lex file have the option to be present one or more times?
2.) To allow "server backup" in the text file to be optional?

I have looked at some references (a couple below) but am struggling to find the right answer:

[This switch statement is working with one Case how to make it multiple case Bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073980/this-switch-statement-is-working-with-one-case-how-to-make-it-multiple-case-biso/21074063#21074063)
[yacc - How to do a if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218999/yacc-how-to-do-a-if-condition/9220644#9220644)
[Bison: how to fix reduce/reduce conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940490/bison-how-to-fix-reduce-reduce-conflict/18945589#18945589)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, depending on what your nesting rules are:

```
commands
    : instances
    ;

instances
    : instance /* or empty if there can be zero instances */
    | instances instance
    ;

instance
    : INSTANCE ids '{' applications '}'
    ;

applications
    : application /* or empty if there can be zero applications */
    | applications application
    ;

application
    : APPLICATION ids '{' servers '}'
    ;

servers
    : server /* or empty if there cabn be zero servers */
    | servers server
    ;

server
    : SERVER backup ids SERVER_IPADDRESS
    {
        // etc. as you have now
    }
    ;

ids
    : ID /* You probably don't want to allow zero IDs */
    | ids ID
    ;

backup
    : /* empty */
    | BACKUP
    ;
```

That should give you the general idea.

Note that you don't need the lex rules for '{' and '}': just have a final rule like this:

```
. return yytext[0];
```

that covers all special characters. With this technique, illegal characters are returned to the parser, which deals with them as syntax errors.